# Headmarks in Appendix using Koma and BibLaTeX / Glossaries

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, koma-script, glossaries, appendices

I am using Koma scrartcl in combination with Biblatex and Glossaries.

In my header I use:

```
\documentclass[twoside, bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl} 
\automark[subsection]{section}
\usepackage[nomain,toc,numberedsection,notranslate,acronym,symbols]{glossaries}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

I have activated the running headmarks with:

```
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

In the appendix of my document I have:

```
\printglossary[type=acronym,style=longhead,title=Liste der Abkürzungen,nonumberlist=true,nopostdot=true]
\printglossary[type=symbols,style=longsymbunit,title=Liste der Formelzeichen,nonumberlist=true,nogroupskip=true]
\printbibliography
```

This setup does not produce consistent headmarks.

Both lists produced by glossaries are numbers with A und B in toc as desired. In the headmark however A and B is missing in front of the heading.

Biblatex does produce a "C   References" as expected both in the toc and in the headmark, however it does put that headmark also as rightmark. I was expecting subsection headmark in Biblatex to be empty and hence only have a mark on the leftside page.

How can I obtain the behaviour I desire? I have extensively searched the internet but did not find any solution.

Comment: Please consider posting a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that we can compile and that reproduces the problem immediately. That way we don't have to make up an entire document from the code snippets you show us, we don't have to make assumptions about your document and we can be sure that we are talking about the same thing. You might also want to consider splitting your question into two separate questions: one about `biblatex` and one about `glossaries`.

Comment: Setting the left and the right mark is consistent with the table of contents, list of figures etc. They all set both marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `biblatex` part of your question should be solved with

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section{#1}}
```

For `glossaries` you might want

```
\renewcommand{\glsglossarymark}[1]{}
```

By default both packages set their titles with starred sectioning commands (`\section*`, `\chapter*`), these commands do not set the headers accordingly, so that has to be done manually with `\@mkboth`. You want the lists in the toc with numbering, so the unstarred sectioning commands (`\section`, `\chapter`) are more appropriate for you. But then there is no need to set the headers manually - in fact here it does more harm than good - so we need to suppress those. This is done by setting `\glsglossarymark` to empty for `glossaries` and by defining the `bibliography` heading to be `\section` only for `biblatex`.

Comment: Thank you for looking into that.
This solves my problems.
I actually found both commands you are using in the specific manuals. However I do not entirely understand why they work. Can you please elaborate on that a bit? Specially, why does setting the glsglossarymark to empty produce a headmark that also contains the desired numbered output?